# Circumcircle intersecting circumcircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

The tangent to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ at $B$ and $C$ meet at $D$. Circumcircle of $\triangle BCD$ meet $AC$ and $AB$ again at $E$ and $F$ respectively. Let $O$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$. Show that $AO$ is perpendicular to $EF$.

This question was sent to me by a friend who loves math. I took many attempts to solve this. I tried to work from the result to get the given but couldn't solve it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the title "circumcircle touching circumcircle"?

Comment: Include your attempt or whatever you have tried in the question so that we may directly address your problem.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know?  State your attempts so that we can see what you're aware of.

Comment: Yeah, so i assumed the conclusion was true and tried to get the statements made. It turned to an angle chasing question which i couldn't solve by bashing. I tried to think of a construction but was unsuccessful in finding one which could prove what i required.

Comment: @Math enthusiast, we are more interested in your written attempt (your angle chasing). At least post an image of it.

Comment: Hint: The circumcenter of $BCD$ is on $EF$, since angles $OAC$, $CEF$ are complementary, as well as $OAB$, $BFE$.

Comment: @Chyrosomath i had already taken that info. But couldnt solve it.

Comment: Extending $AO$ cuts $EF$ perpendicularly because $OAE$ and $AEF$ are complementary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\angle ACB = x$ and let line $AO$ meet line $EF$ at $G$. Then

- $\angle BFE = \angle BEC = \angle BCA = x$
- Since $\angle AOB  = 2\angle BCA = 2x$ we have $ \angle BAO (= \angle ABO) = 90-x$
- Observe triangle $AFG$...

[image]